# How can I fix this code to get all prime numbers within a range?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I am testing my algorithm and trying to print all prime numbers within a range. I think the code is logical but it keeps printing the wrong output i.e the unfiltered list of numbers.

```
function sumPrimes(num) {
  // Check all numbers for primality
  let a = []
  let b = []
  for (let i = 2; i <= num; i++) {
      a.push(i)
      b.push(i)
  }
  //console.log(a)
  return a.filter(function(item) {
    for(let j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
      if(item !== b[j] && item % b[j] != 0) {
        return true
      } 
    }
    return false; 
  })
}
sumPrimes(977);
```

Comment: According to your logic, you just need one division with a non-zero remainder to mark your number as prime. What do you thing `2 % 977` returns?

Comment: Helps to know what a prime number *is* before making such erroneous code. Ok, what a prime number *is*: on n where in n is set of 1 to +infinity, only one factor, and that being `1`, technically two factors if we include "n" itself.

Comment: Likely the wording of "prime" on whoever named it such is that `1` as the first countable number is "prime", in terms of a division. Side thought this is worth investigating on historical value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues. First `j` should start being equal to `2`. Otherwise it will see every value has a factor of 1. We can also skip your check to make sure `b[j]` is not `item` if we don't go through the entire span of `b` and instead just up to `item`. The other main issue is that the `return true` and `return false` are backwards.

The next issues are that you don't really need some parts. For example `b[j]` will always be equal to `j + 2` so there is no need to build `b`.

```js
function sumPrimes(num) {
  // Check all numbers for primality
  let a = []
  for (let i = 2; i <= num; i++) {
      a.push(i)
  }

  return a.filter(function(item) {
    for(let j = 2; j < item; j++) {
      if(item % j === 0) {
        // j is a factor so we shouldn't keep it and instead skip it
        return false;
      } 
    }
    // We know that all of the values up to item are not factors so we keep it
    return true; 
  })
}

console.log(sumPrimes(977));
```

Plus we can skip adding every value to `a` if we apply the filtering as we add the values.

```js
function getPrimesUpTo(num) {
  let primes = [];

  // Check each value
  for (let i = 2; i <= num; i++) {
      let hasFactors = false;

      // Search for any factors before adding it to our list of primes
      for (let possibleFactor = 2; possibleFactor < i; possibleFactor++) {
          if (i % possibleFactor === 0) {
              hasFactors = true;
              break;
          }
      }
      
      if (!hasFactors) {
          primes.push(i);
      }
  }

  return primes;
}

console.log(getPrimesUpTo(977));
```

Comment: Prime is a hard problem to solve algorithmically because its (1) not deterministic, and (2) not random. Hence it serves as a great value (as in upper limits) in cryptography